# D365 Sending Email as Admin Error:the number of allowed connections to the mailbox Admin CRM has been exceeded

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have Admin user which send Email (Notification to users) on daily basis.
When I checked Admin's Mailbox I found below Error

When I Test & Enable Mailbox for Admin, outgoing Email Status is "Failure"

> The number of allowed connections to the mailbox Admin CRM has been
>   exceeded

When I get Error log  for alert is shows as below

> ActivityId: 4a52633a-15e0-41e3-9558-040bcb9097c2
>
> > Error : Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The message couldn't be sent because the sender's submission quota was
> >     exceeded. Please try again later., The message can't be submitted
> >     because the sender's submission quota was exceeded.    at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1
> >     items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition,
> >     Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
> >     at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.CreateItem(Item
> >     item, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition,
> >     Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)    at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId
> >     parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1
> >     sendInvitationsMode...

Does anyone have Idea where to look for next steps for solving this issue?

---

**Edit 1**

**Resolution for above Error**

*Error above Issue was some (don't know probably license revoking) from IT of customer. Once license was assigned above Error was resolved.*

But I got another Error as

> activityId: 30c87b76-b493-e711-80e2-1458d043c6f0
>
> > Error : Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The user account which was used to submit this request does not have
> >     the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account.,
> >     Cannot submit message.    at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1
> >     items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition,
> >     Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
> >     at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.CreateItem(Item
> >     item, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition,
> >     Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)    at
> >     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId
> >     parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1
> >     sendInvitationsMode)    at Microsoft.Exchange.W...

Now this was some serious issue which needed Microsoft Intervention.

Above Error was caused because in Office 365 there were 2 Users, one with abc@xyz.de as username and other user with abc@xyz.de as Primary Email. Note UserName was different. But aby@xyz.de UserName, user not licensed and CRM was confused which user to verfiy against.

**Resolution**

*Deleting UnLicensed User with username abc@xyz.de did solved our issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Sending limits across Office 365 options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#sending-limits-across-office-365-options) section of the [Exchange Online Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits) documentation. It looks like you are trying to send too many emails within the 1 minute window.

> Message rate limit: Message rate limits determine how many messages a user can send from their Exchange Online account within a specified period of time. This limit helps prevent over consumption of system resources by a single sender. If a user submits messages at a rate that exceeds the limit via SMTP client submission, the messages will be rejected and the client will need to retry.

Consider splitting the email notifications up into smaller batches, spread over a wider period of time.

Comment: Yes your initial Investigation was correct however this was not the root cause.
I updated my question if in case you are interested to know.